# matrix transformation with respect to basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ß = (b_1,...,b_n)$ be a basis of the vector space $V$, let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation of $V$, and let B be the $ß$-matrix of $T$.

(a) Prove that $v \in \ker(T)$ if and only if $[v]_B \in \ker(B)$.

(b) Prove that $v \in \text{Im(T)}$ if and only if $[v]_B \in \text
{Im(T)}$.

(c) Prove that $T$ is an isomorphism if and only if $B$ is invertible.

can someone explain to me how to go about this

Comment: Where exactly do you need help with? what have you tried?

Comment: Do you understand what it means for $B$ to be the $\beta$-matrix of $T$, Alizeh?

Answer (score 0):

If $Tv = w,$ then because $B$ is the $\beta$-matrix of $T,$ $B[v]_B = [w]_B.$

(a) Assume first that $v \in \ker(T).$ Then $Tv = 0,$ so $B[v]_B = [0]_B = 0.$ Hence, $[v]_B \in \ker(B).$ Conversely, assume that $[v]_B \in \ker(B).$ Then $B[v]_B = 0 = [0]_B,$ so $Tv = 0.$ Hence, $v \in \ker(T).$ Thus, $v \in \ker(T)$ if and only if $[v]_B \in \ker(B).$

(b) Assume first that $v \in \mbox{Im}(T).$ Then there exists a $u \in V$ such that $Tu = v,$ so $B[u]_B = [v]_B.$ Hence, $[v]_B \in \mbox{Im}(B)$ (note that I corrected a typo in the question). Conversely, assume that $[v]_B \in \mbox{Im}(B).$ Then there exists a $u \in V$ such that $B[u]_B = [v]_B,$ so $Tu = v.$ Hence, $v \in \mbox{Im}(T).$ Thus, $v \in \mbox{Im}(T)$ if and only if $[v]_B \in \mbox{Im}(B).$

(c) Assume first that $T$ is an isomorphism. Then by definition, $T$ is a non-singular linear transformation of $V$ onto $V,$ so $T$ is invertible (see Theorem 9 on page 81 of [*Linear Algebra* by Hoffman and Kunze](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit)).  So if $Tv = w,$ then $v = T^{-1}w,$ i.e., if $B[v]_B = [w]_B,$ then $[v]_B = B^{-1}[w]_B.$ Hence, $B$ is invertible. Conversely, assume that $B$ is invertible. Then by the same reasoning as above, $T$ is invertible, and by the same Theorem 9, $T$ is non-singular and onto. Hence, $T$ is an isomorphism. Thus, $T$ is an isomorphism if and only if $B$ is invertible.